# django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf search in text field with space returns null

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, elk

I have the following index in my Elasticsearch:

```
  "mappings": { 
      "properties": {     
        "content": {
            "type": "text"
        },
       .
       .
       .
```

When I use kibana console searching in `content` field by a value such `This is`, It return all documents with phrase `This is` in the content, but using django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf (and django rest framework)  it returns nothing and the search only works by values with no spaces, I mean If i search for the word `This` it returns the results as wished.

My document:

```
@INDEX.doc_type
class PostDocument(Document):
    content = fields.TextField()
    ...
```

my serializer:

```
class PostDocumentSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    """Serializer for the Post document."""
    content = serializers.CharField()
    ...
```

my viewset:

```
class PostDocumentView(DocumentViewSet):
    document = PostDocument
    serializer_class = PostDocumentSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination

    filter_backends = [
        FilteringFilterBackend,
        IdsFilterBackend,
        OrderingFilterBackend,
        DefaultOrderingFilterBackend,
        SearchFilterBackend,
        SuggesterFilterBackend,
    ]
    # Define search fields
    search_fields = (
        'content',
        ...
    )
    filter_fields = {
        'content': {
            'field': 'content',
            'lookups': [
                LOOKUP_QUERY_CONTAINS,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_IN
            ]
        },
    }
```

and the URL to test is:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/social_networks/posts_search/?format=json&page=1&content=This is`

Comment: Try http://127.0.0.1:8000/social_networks/posts_search/?format=json&page=1=&content=This%20is

Comment: does not work @Crosby

Answer (score 0):

Use [django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf.herokuapp.com](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf.herokuapp.com) as a playground.

Searching with space [works for me](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf.herokuapp.com/search/books/?search=summary:Ut%20labore).

The source code of the playground app can be found on GitHub at [barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf-heroku-demo](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf-heroku-demo).